# Why iron-router does not render carousel?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, owl-carousel

it works perfectly when I make it like this

```
<body>
{{> carousel}}
</body>
<Template name="carousel">
....here the code of carousel...
</Template>
```

but when I use iron-router to render the Template; it does not render carousel

```
<body>
{{rendreRouter}}
</body>
<Template name="carousel">
    ....here the code of carousel...
 </Template>

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('carousel',{
    path: '/'
  });
});
```

Comment: Your example use **{{rendreRouter}}**, I believe **{{renderRouter}}** should be used

Comment: but when i use it ; there is no carousel's image rendered, i don't know why or how fix it as i'm newbie on Meteor

Comment: create basic meteor app which reproduces this issue and push it to some github repository, send me link, I will take a look

Comment: i've  created in github and the link is  [link](https://github.com/nwabdou85/carousel.git)

Answer (score 1):

I'm coming to the conclusion that the [documentation you're reading is not in sync with the code base](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#rendering-the-router).  In fact, [it looks like the feature is gone](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/593).

In my own exploration of the topic, [I have an alternate solution at that may work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612913/meteors-ironrouter-isnt-doing-renderrouter-as-expected-or-documented) at the bottom of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Init your carousel in template.rendered hook, for example my template is named main_slider.

```
Template.main_slider.rendered = function() {
    // init carousel here
};
```