# Meteor's iron:router isn't doing {{renderRouter}} as expected or documented

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've got a very simple template problem going on that appears to be similar to [this guy's problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328368/why-iron-router-does-not-rendre-carousel), though I've tried to build a simple example to demonstrate the problem and hopefully have someone explain to me how to fix or work around it.

Although as I'm doing some online research, it may be that [the official documentation](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#rendering-the-router) is out of date with the code. The reason I haven't bought into accepting that just yet is that [the problem](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/64) seems to [have existed](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/599) for a while, the dates on such articles in forums appears to be fairly old, and there's talk of it being fixed. There's also talk [the feature is gone](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/593).  What's the *new way*, if there is one?

I'm using [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com) 0.9.0.1 with [iron:router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) 0.9.1.  Specifically, I set up my project like this:

```
$ meteor create ironTest
$ cd ironTest
$ meteor add iron:router
$ meteor
```

Pointing my browser at `http://localhost:3000/` as instructed, shows the default project. So far so good.

Now make **ironTest.html** contain this:

```html
<body>
  <h1>Before</h1>
      {{renderRouter}}
  <h2>Afterward</h2>
</body>

<template name="hello">
    Hello Template
</template>
<template name="goodbye">
    Goodbye Template
</template>
```

Make **ironTest.js** contain this:

```js
Router.configure({
  autoRender: true  // we will experiment with this Boolean shortly
});

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('hello');
  this.route('goodbye');
});
```

If you go to the routes `http://localhost:3000/hello` and `http://localhost:3000/goodbye`, you'll see the templates correctly render [as expected and documented](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#rendering-the-router), appended to the `<body>` element, so it appears *after* the `<h2>` element.

[**According to the current documentation for iron:router**](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#rendering-the-router), one should be able to set the `autoRender` property to `false`, and the template should no longer be appended to the `<body>` element, but rather be injected where the [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com) (okay, [Spacebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md)) element `{{renderRouter}}` is, that is, between the `<h1>` and `<h2>` elements.

When I try this, visually it doesn't do anything.  Opening a JavaScript Console to look at errors shows none.  Although, by deliberately going to an invalid route it will show a missing template router exception, showing the routing code is indeed working.

Does anyone know how to coerce the code above into working?

---

For the curious, I've got a working simplistic equivalent that might be of use to others working this problem.

This new **ironTest.html** uses a template (for a layout) with no `<body>`:

```html
<template name="main">
  <h1>Before</h1>
      {{> yield}}
  <h2>Afterward</h2>
</template>

<template name="hello">
    Hello Template
</template>
<template name="goodbye">
    Goodbye Template
</template>
```

This **ironTest.js** instead uses a layout:

```js
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate : 'main'
});

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('hello');
  this.route('goodbye');
});
```

It's worth an aside that this solution doesn't work for me, as I don't want a global layout, and have concern that riddling layouts in the route themselves is a tighter coupling than desired for my purposes.

I'm currently looking for a way to dump debugging log information from the Router as it performs transitions, but that's another story.

Comment: You might be interested by my approach when it comes to handling complex layout design in a Meteor + iron:router application. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602878/appropriate-way-of-using-yield-with-region/25613756#25613756

Comment: I share the sentiment that mixing layout and routing together is not a good idea... What if one wants to use a different layout strategy than the one offered?